# How to pass nested Json into my http API in Dart

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart

I need to pass json data into my http APIs. I am not able to find the right way to do this yet. Here's my code snippet:
For all interactions to/from API, I have created an Dbhelper class.
Here's my Dbhelper class

```
class Dbhelper {
  String fbody; // json parameter 
  Map result; // Response json for the api called

  Dbhelper({this.fbody});

  Future<void> executeData() async {
    try {
    //Make post request
    Response response = await post('http://<my domain>/api/GetInfo',headers: {"content-type":"application/json"},body: $fbody);
    var deviceinfo = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print('In dbhelper $deviceinfo');
    result = deviceinfo;
    } catch(e) {
      print('Something occured $e');
      result = null;
    }
  }
}
```

This is what i am trying to do. I have login class which takes input from UI - UserName and password and need to pass this into Dbhelper object. 
the intended json to be passed in my API  is :

```
{
  "strjson":{ "cUserName":"sandy" , "cPassword":"12345" },
  "strSPName":"App_Userlogin"
}
```

```
toMap(String u, String p ){
    return {
      "strSPName":"App_userregister",
      "strjson":{
        "cUserName":u,
        "cPassword":p
      }
    };
  }
  void _checkLogin(String u , String p) async {
    try {
      Map inputs = toMap(u,p);
      print(inputs);
      Dbhelper db = Dbhelper(fbody: inputs);
      await db.executeData();
      User user = User.fromJson(db.result);
      if (user.uid >0)
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('home');
      else
        print("User not found");
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      User user = User(uid:0,username:'',userbalance: 0);
    }
  }
```

Please help me what I am missing in this

Comment: can you be specific about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

While passing body to http.post request . Try passing body inside single quotes.

```
Response response = await post('http://<my domain>/api/GetInfo',headers: {"content-type":"application/json"},body: '$fbody');
```

If this doesn't work, you can try encoding your body in json format using jsonEncode as shown

```
body: jsonEncode(<String, String> {'uname':'SomeName',})
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

Json that I have posted in body..

```
{
  "user": {
  "UserName": "username",
  "password": "password",
  "Name": "name",
  "Email": "email"
 }
}
```

Your Post Api call be like:

```
Future<User> postUser(String username, String password, String name, String 
 email) async {

 Paste your api url here
 String url = '';
 final response = await http.post(apiUrl, headers: {
   // Enter your headers parameter if needed
   //  E.g: 
   'Authorization' : 'xyz',
   'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
  },
 body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
  'UserName' : username,
  'password' : password,
  'Name' : name,
  'Email' : email
 }));

   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
     print(data);
      return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
   } else {
   throw Exception('Failed to post user.');
   }
 }
```

Your model be like:

```
   class User {
      User? user;

      User({this.user});

      User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        user = json['user'] != null ? new User.fromJson(json['user']) : null;
      }

   Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
       final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
         if (this.user != null) {
           data['user'] = this.user!.toJson();
          }
       return data;
      }
     }

  class User {
     String? userName;
     String? password;
     String? name;
     String? email;

      User({this.userName, this.password, this.name, this.email});

      User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
         userName = json['UserName'];
         password = json['password'];
         name = json['Name'];
         email = json['Email'];
       }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
       final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
       data['UserName'] = this.userName;
       data['password'] = this.password;
       data['Name'] = this.name;
       data['Email'] = this.email;
      return data;
     }
    }
```